# "start /affinity" equivalent in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, windows, multithreading, winapi

The `start` Windows shell command (in cmd.exe) appears to be able to start a process **with** a chosen processor affinity, rather than starting the process **then** setting the chosen processor affinity some (small) period of time after it has started.

```
start /affinity 2 something.exe
```

Is there a way to do the same from within a .NET application either with or without using P-Invoke? Calling out to `cmd.exe /C start ...` doesn't count.

The `Process` class has the `ProcessorAffinity` property, but it throws `InvalidOperationException` if you try to set it before having called the `Start` method.

Comment: Are you sure that internally `start` doesn't start process then set affinity?

Comment: @Andrey how do we find out what start does internally?

Comment: i think my assumption was wrong, looks like Jerry Coffin knows the secret

Comment: @Andrey: note that I said "I suspect" -- I haven't actually looked at the code to the start command to check. In any case, imitating it exactly is less interesting than knowing how to get your code to do what you want.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin your assumption looked much more solid and reasonable for me compared to my. Btw, start is not a program but part of cmd i think, it is not easy to disasm that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect what the start command does in this case is start the process suspended (i.e., passes `CREATE_SUSPENDED` when calling [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa908775.aspx)), then sets the processor affinity, then resumes the thread.

This way, while the process *exists* without the process affinity having been set, by the time it starts *executing* the processor affinity has been set, so it only ever runs on the designated processor.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that you can set processor affinity before starting the process because the first parameter of [SetProcessAffinityMask Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686223%28VS.85%29.aspx) is handle to the process.

On the other hand, there is a program called [Imagecfg](http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/tips/jsi-tip-3542-how-can-i-permanently-set-the-processor-affinity-for-an-application-.aspx) which allows to permanently set processor affinity for an executable but I am not sure how it works.